# How to make a boxplot from summary statistics in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to create a boxplot with ggplot in R, but I have some problems. I know how to create in general a boxplot. For example like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(y=number, x=pod)) + geom_boxplot()
print(p)
```

However, in my case I have only the mean (0,892), median (0,863 +-0,0858) and the range (0,621-1,132). I am not sure how to create a boxplot if I do not have all the values. Is it possible to create a boxplot with just these three parameters? Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much.
Best regards,
Hannah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a boxplot from the summary stats like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(1), middle = .863, lower = .863 - .0858, upper = .863 + .0858, ymin = .621, ymax = 1.132), stat = "identity", width = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I am trying to add the mean to the boxplot. I have tried this code: mean(0.892) ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(1), middle = .863, lower = .863 - .0858, upper = .863 + .0858, ymin = .621, ymax = 1.132), stat = "identity", width = .5) +stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red"). Unfortunately, it is not working. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: stat_summary will not work as there is no data. But you could add your mean using e.g. `geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = .75, xmax = 1.25, x = factor(1), y = 0.892), colour="red")` which gives the mean as a pointrange. BTW: The xmin and xmax are set as 1 +/- width / 2

Comment: Is there an easy way to add the outliers (multiple per group of data), other than using `geom_point` separately ?

Comment: Hi @steveb. I just had a look at the docs. But I'm afraid there isn't an option to pass a vector of outliers. So you have to put them in a dataframe and add them via `geom_point`.

Comment: @stefan It appears that way. I just did that but also had to include the additional columns with `middle`, `lower`, `upper`, `ymin`, and `ymax` (I put zero in for values) because ggplot complained about them being missing. I will have to just use `geom_point`. Thanks for looking into this.