Adding outliers to a boxplot from precomputed summary statistics
I am working with a large (50 x 800 000) sparse matrix (dgCMatrix) and want to plot a boxplot for the initial inspection of the data. This is a matrix of numeric items, with named rows (genes) and named columns (cells). The best solution I have found is to compute the relevant stats via sparseMatrixStats::rowQuantiles() and feed them directly to a boxplot geom.
I am aware of the approach for geom_boxplot() with precomputed values (this works seamlessly!), see links below, but I run into problems when trying to add outliers via an additional geom.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628847/geom-boxplot-with-precomputed-values
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426913/how-to-make-a-boxplot-from-summary-statistics-in-ggplot2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341850/group-specified-geom-boxplot-from-summary-statistics-fails-to-generate-boxplots
In summary, I compute a data frame with relevant quantiles/summary statistics and feed them into geom_boxplot(). I also create a (still rather large) data frame with outliers, which I want to add onto the boxplot via geom_point() or geom_jitter() (as far as I am aware geom_boxplot() does not have a slot to add these in the precomputed approach). The problem arises when trying to add the outliers to the boxplot:
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `y`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

This is a toy example of my problem:
genes=factor(c('a', 'b', 'c'))

# df with quantiles (simplified for brevity, with non-standard lower and upper hinges)
df <- data.frame(gene=genes, 
                 zero=c(1, 3, 0),
                 twentyfive=c(2, 4, 8),
                 fifty=c(5, 5, 12),
                 seventyfive=c(7, 9, 12),
                 hundred=c(8, 12, 15))

# Option 1 - only one outlier per gene 
df_outliers1 <- data.frame(gene=rep(genes, 1), 
                           value = sample(0:1, 3, replace = TRUE))

# Option 2 - more than one outlier per gene
df_outliers2 <- data.frame(gene=rep(genes, 1), 
                           value = c(sample(0:1, 3, replace = TRUE), sample(12:16, 3, replace=TRUE)))

# Option 1 - using df_outliers1 - works
ggplot(df, aes(x=gene, ymin=zero, lower=twentyfive, middle=fifty, upper=seventyfive, ymax=hundred)) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat='identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=df_outliers1$value)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))

# Option 2 - using df_outliers2 - error (as above)!
ggplot(df, aes(x=gene, ymin=zero, lower=twentyfive, middle=fifty, upper=seventyfive, ymax=hundred)) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat='identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=df_outliers2$value)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))



Curiously, when there is exactly one outlier point per gene (Option 1, using df_outliers1), the approach above works perfectly well. But as soon as there are more points per gene (Option 2, using df_outliers2), the error occurs.
What is the best way to address this problem? (Or is there a better way of tackling the sparse matrix directly?)

Note that layers inherit aesthetics by default. If an aesthetic is not shared, don't specify it in the main ggplot() call. Also, avoid using "$" in aes() calls. Use data= with different data sources.
Try
ggplot(df, aes(x=gene)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=zero, lower=twentyfive, middle=fifty, upper=seventyfive, ymax=hundred), stat='identity') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=value), data=df_outliers2) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))



Thank you! Yes, it was very sloppy of me, I usually do not use "$" in aes() calls...

One nice thing about ggplot is that you can supply individual layers with their own data. This should work, using your example data:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = df,
               aes(x=gene, ymin=zero, lower=twentyfive, middle=fifty, upper=seventyfive, ymax=hundred),
               stat = 'identity'
  ) +
  geom_point(data = df_outliers2, aes(x = gene, y=value))


This seems to work, thank you! It seems that in this case it is desirable to put data in the geom, and not in ggplot()...

I have found another workaround, which works with data in ggplot, using inherit.aes = FALSE:

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=gene, ymin=zero, lower=twentyfive, middle=fifty, upper=seventyfive, ymax=hundred)) + geom_boxplot(stat='identity') + geom_point(data=df_outliers2, aes(x=gene, y=value), inherit.aes=FALSE)
